# navbar error when collapsed | Bootstrap 4

Tags: mobile, alignment, bootstrap-4, navbar

Navbar-toggle button was on the top-right both web and mobile mode, but when the navbar collapsed on mobile mode something gone wrong (last pic).

I know it's because my code's line order, but I don't know how to fix it.

Web mode:

[image]

Mobile Mode:

[image]

Collapsed mobile mode:

[image]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EVENT</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <?=$_SESSION['name'];?>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="login/logout.php">Logout</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item" style="float:top">
      <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Create">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this problem would be:

1. Put the code for the red button after the navbar brand item in the HTML
2. Give it the classes `ml-auto order-lg-last`. The former means "margin-left:auto" and the latter will reorder that button on screens that are large (`lg`) or larger and put it in the last position. `ml-auto` will then actually push it to the right.
3. Give the toggler (that should come after the red button in the HTML) the `ml-2` class to get a bit of space between it and the red button.

Click "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">EVENT</a>

    <div class="nav-item ml-auto order-lg-last">
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Create">
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-2" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <?=$_SESSION['name'];?>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="login/logout.php">Logout</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```